# W3C validator and pagespeed warning?

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, w3c, pagespeed-insights

If I use this code, W3C validator shows warning. (Bad value 100% for attribute height on element img: Expected a digit but saw % instead.)

`<img src="" width="100%" height="100%" alt=""> or  <img src="" width="100%" height="auto;" alt="">`

if I use this pagespeed shows warning. (Image elements do not have explicit width and height values)

`<img src="" style="max-width: 100%; height: auto;" alt="">` (no problem for w3c but problem for pagespeed)

**I didn't want to make the height and width values fixed as it is mobile compatible**. (mobil responsive) But what is the best code without errors?

What is the correct code without W3C validator or pagespeed warning? thanks

Comment: The height and width of an image describe the image, not how it is to be displayed. Give the height and width attributes as numbers (i.e. describing its pixel dimensions), then put the size you want them displayed (e.g. as a percentage) in the CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Width and height attributes must be integers and not percentages. They are used to know the aspect-ratio of the image.

To keep images responsive you use CSS to restrict the dimensions (but based on the aspect-ratio to keep them in scale - the original dimensions are needed so the browser can calculate the actual height for the `height: auto` part).

So you basically need a combo of the two options:

```html
<img src="" width="400" height="200" style="max-width: 100%; height: auto;" alt="">
```

For more details see this article I wrote on the subject: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2020/03/setting-height-width-images-important-again/